# Pfaffian of unitary transformed matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $U$ be a unitary matrix, and $U^\dagger$ be its Hermitian conjugate.

What is $\mathrm{Pf}(U^\dagger AU)$?

Since $\mathrm{Pf}(U^\dagger AU)^2=\mathrm{det}(U^\dagger AU)=\mathrm{det} (A)=\mathrm{Pf}(A)^2$, then $\mathrm{Pf}(U^\dagger AU)=\pm \mathrm{Pf}(A) $

**How to decide which sign to take?**

Comment: It's a non-sense. If $A$ is skew symmetric, then, in general, $U^*AU$ is not skew symmetric (except, for instance, if $U$ is orthogonal).

Comment: @loupblanc You mean talking about $\mathrm{Pf} U^\dagger A U$ is a nonsense, because it is not skew symmetric in general and Pfaffian is defined only in skew symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ buzhidao , take $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\-a&0\end{pmatrix},U=diag(e^{i\alpha},e^{i\beta})$  (where $a,\alpha,\beta$ are real). Then $U^*AU=\begin{pmatrix}0&ae^{i(\beta-\alpha)}\\-ae^{i(\alpha-\beta)}&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&u\\-\bar{u}&0\end{pmatrix}$. Finally $\det(U^*AU)=a^2=u\bar{u}$.

$a^2$ is the square of a polynomial in the entries of $A$ and $u\bar{u}$ is not the square of a polynomial in the entries of $U^*AU$ (except if $u=\pm a$).